# Is it possible to minimize MySQL latency in for selects?

Tags: mysql, go, prepared-statement

I'm dealing with an application that runs in two zones. Both talk to the same MySQL in one of the zones, where (excuse the pun):

```
BEGIN (same zone): ~1ms
SELECT (same zone): ~1ms
BEGIN (different zone): ~60ms
SELECT (different zone): ~120ms
```

The timings are extremely consistent. I have a theory that the real network latency is 60ms, however, the SELECT is doing two roundtrips. My guess is that it's fetching the data as a separate trip to preparing the query. In almost all cases there will be only one row returned.

If this is plausible, is there a way to tell go or MySQL to do the whole process in a single round trip?

Comment: check skip-name-resolve is in the MySQL configuration. reverse DNS lookups when there is a failure could be about this time interval.

Comment: In case of prepared statements the prepare and the actual execution of the statement is always a two step process, there is no way around it. If a prepare take significantly longer, then you have some other issue, such as network latency, so 7ou should resolve that.